# Run a TypeScript interpreter in an inferior process window

Tags: programming

Are there any alternatives to ts-comint.el?

https://github.com/emacs-typescript/ts-comint

It's old and unmaintained.

I'm using tide, but I don't see how I can transpile/evaluate the code directly from emacs. Are people switching to a terminal to compile and run or are there some ways I haven't discovered yet?;)

Comment: It's old but it's not clear it's unmaintained: there is one issue from May 7, 2020 and there was a reply to it (I believe from the author) on May 14.

Comment: sure, but are there other options? I'm having trouble with it and I wonder what other people use. Do you switch to eshell to run tsc?

Comment: I don't use TypeScript at all.